# limit RAM growth

Tags: ram, clickhouse

RAM usage grows stably from some low values to almost 100% during several days. Then falls back to almost 0 and starts growing slowly again.
I am OK with this behaviour but would like to limit the upper limit to, say, 80%. As far as I see, max_server_memory_usage_to_ram_ratio config directive affects only the speed of its growth.
Two replicated ClickHouse servers with the same amount of available RAM share the same behaviour.
Is there a way to limit RAM usage in this way?

ClickHouse server version: 22.2.2.1
OS: Rocky Linux release 8.6 (Green Obsidian)
Prometheus metric to measure RAM growth: mem_used_percent
Available RAM: 16G

Answer (score 0):

You mostly have two setings when it comes to memomry management:

`max_memory_usage` and `max_server_memory_usage_to_ram_ratio`. Y ou can't control how much memory is going to be used over time as it mostly depends on what you are going to do with ClickHouse.